# Foundation Reveal modal not opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation, reveal.js

I'm having trouble getting the Reveal modal to trigger and I'm at a loss.

At first I thought it was a JS conflict so I removed everything else on the site and boiled it down to the basics, some CSS, some JS and some HTML as you see below (and at http://test.jephchristoff.com/modal.html) and still no luck. The modal doesn't trigger and I'm stuck.

Can anyone help me?

```
<head>
<style>
.reveal-modal-bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #000000;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
    z-index: 1004;
    display: none;
    left: 0; }
.reveal-modal, dialog {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1005;
    width: 100vw;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 1.11111rem;
    border: solid 1px #666666;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 1.66667rem; }
.reveal-modal .close-reveal-modal, .reveal-modal dialog {
    font-size: 2.22222rem;
    line-height: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.44444rem;
    right: 0.61111rem;
    color: #AAAAAA;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Click Me For A Modal</a>
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
    <h2>Awesome. I have it.</h2>
<p class="lead">Your couch.  It is mine.</p>
<p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="foundation.reveal.js"></script>
<script>$(document).foundation();</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put the right order on the js and css files:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).foundation();
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/hs2ddcfx/2/

Comment: Thanks. That's it. I'm not sure why their example in the "Using the Javascript" section of [this page](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html) only has:

`<script>$(document).foundation();</script>`

Comment: Because you don't need to load a callback inside a document ready function so I'd recommend just firing this after the foundation script/s: <script>$(document).foundation();</script>